# How to convert a 'Featureset' object to Python DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, api

My api query returned a table. I tried to convert it to df. However, it produced AttributeError saying 'Featureset' object has no attribute. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/wbgapi/) is the information about the API. Below are the query codes.

```
import wbgapi as wb
wb.source.info()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by converting the 'Featureset' object into a dictionary then extract data from the dictionary.

```
import wbgapi as wb
import pandas as pd

table = wb.source.info()
table_dict = vars(table)

df_source = pd.DataFrame(table_dict.get('items'))
```